# definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I import my database all the tables are imported successfully, but when I'm trying to access the "views" then I got the message below on phpmyadmin's screen

```
references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) 
or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

Please tell me what is wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when importing a **view** into a new database. Unlike table, when importing view it includes **previous host** line as follows

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`previoushost`@`localhost`
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_user`  
    AS SELECT `user`.`id`,`user`.`name` ....
```

Now Backup this view(incase something happens), and DROP IT and create it as

```
CREATE VIEW `view_user`  
    AS SELECT `user`.`id`,`user`.`name` .....
```

Answer (score -3):

One can use the SQL to grant the rights alike:

```
GRANT ALL ON * . * TO 'your-user-name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password'
```

Comment: This works, but basically you throw away all security with this...

Comment: Grant everything to some random user allows you to delete all the data (obvious), or amend/replace data (non-obvious).